# Azure - creating new Directory - question about permissions to do so

Tags: azure, directory, permissions

Searched through the SO, internet, docs and couldn't find the best answer for this. Might be that you will know the answer or will transfer me where appropriate.

In Azure we do have a Directory with 1 subscription assigned. Within this directory we have a user, this user:
* IS the OWNER of subscription
* IS NOT the AzureAD Administrator (user has not additional rights). This user is no able to add/remove users/groups with the currect Ad.

However what we found is that such a user CAN create ne directory, where he can be automatically assigned to Global Admin role (create/remove users/groups etc) and CAN move above memntioned subscription to newly created directory he owns and manage.

This is of course not what we expect as we want to have a control of any AD and user access management.

I couldn't find yet a way to deny all user within directory to create separate directory.

Do you have some experience with this and/or some advice?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about it ;) Just found option "Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal" under AzureAD which restrict the access to AD itself.